# Angular Material radio buttons does not work on Android 4.4

Tags: android, angular, angular-material

I use angular 6, material 7 for developing web app. But the radio buttons does not work in browsers Android 4.4. The same issue i discover on official site angular material v5. See the picture.

[image: Radio buttons does not works, it shows circles only]

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material supports only the most recent two versions of all major browsers.
See the browser support section in the docs: https://github.com/angular/material2#browser-and-screen-reader-support.